# AJAX POST JSON data and receiving back javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm using a Jquery Ajax POS request to send JSON data from my chrome extension to my server, then having a response sent containing javascript to be executed on the client side. 
How should I set my contentType and dataType to achieve this? I'm currently getting a 'contentType is not defined' error message.. code below:

client.js

```
      request("https://a304cff8.ngrok.io/api/panels/hitme", "post", "json", {apples})
    .done(function(res){
      console.log(res)

    })
  })
 function request(url, method, contentType, data){
 return $.ajax({
url: url,
method: method, 
contentType: contentType,
data: data
})
}
```

Comment: You are using an uninitialized variable: `contentType`. Initialize that with something appropriate or omit it all together.

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) clearly states the possible values of `dataType`.

Comment: I've updated my code in the question, I need the data posted to server to be in json so I can get the '.length' of the string.. However the code above is just sending 'undefined'?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function demo () {
        $(".abc").click( function(e){
            if(e.which == '10' || e.which=='13') {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            var xyz=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'jquery-data.php',
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'JSON',
                data:{........},
                success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                   // showing return status
                }
            });
        });
    }
```